# ansible, json_query - How to get data from JSON with conditions from two different levels

Tags: json, ansible

Hello Developer Community!

I'm currently working on developing some Ansible playbooks to manage Citrix NetScaler configuration and would like to ask for some help about the following. I have the following data structure defined:

```
{
"msg": [
    {
        "healthmonitor": "YES",
        "lbmonitor_binding": [
            {
                "monitor_name": "MONITOR_foo1"
            },
            {
                "monitor_name": "MONITOR_bar1"
            }
        ],
        "name": "LBSVC_foo1",
        "port": "80",
        "servername": "LBSRV_foo1",
        "servicetype": "HTTP"
    },
    {
        "healthmonitor": "YES",
        "lbmonitor_binding": [
            {
                "monitor_name": "MONITOR_foo2"
            }
        ],
        "name": "LBSVC_foo2",
        "port": "80",
        "servername": "LBSRV_foo2",
        "servicetype": "HTTP"
    },
    {
        "healthmonitor": "YES",
        "lbmonitor_binding": [
            {
                "monitor_name": "MONITOR_foo1"
            }
        ],
        "name": "LBSVC_foo3",
        "port": "80",
        "servername": "LBSRV_foo3",
        "servicetype": "HTTP"
    }
]}
```

I would like to get an entry from "msg" list using json_query filters:

**Condition 1:**

```
 - "name": "LBSVC_foo1"
 - "monitor_name": "MONITOR_foo1"
```

**Expected result 1:**

```
    {
    "healthmonitor": "YES",
    "lbmonitor_binding": [
        {
            "monitor_name": "MONITOR_foo1"
        },
        {
            "monitor_name": "MONITOR_bar1"
        }
    ],
    "name": "LBSVC_foo1",
    "port": "80",
    "servername": "LBSRV_foo1",
    "servicetype": "HTTP",
},
```

**Condition 2:**

```
 - "name": "LBSVC_foo3"
 - "monitor_name": "MONITOR_bar1"
```

**Expected result 2:**
[Empty]

I have tried to use some JSON queries on [this validator](https://jsonpath.com/) page, but they do not work, I always get empty or partial results or incorrect json_query format errors.  For example:

```
$.msg.[?(@.name == 'LBSVC_foo1')] && lbmonitor_binding.[?(@.monitor_name == 'MONITOR_foo1')]
```

Could anyone please point me to the right direction, how json_query format should look like in case I have conditions defined located in two "different levels" in JSON structure ("name" and "monitor_name")? Thank You very much in advance!

Comment: You have used a validator for jsonpath queries. The ansible `json_query` filter uses [jmespath](https://jmespath.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, yes You are right. On the validator webpage, I used the jsonpath format for testing, independently from Ansible, just tried to find out how to make it work.

Comment: => `{{ msg | json_query("[?name=='LBSVC_foo3' && lbmonitor_binding[?monitor_name=='MONITOR_bar1']]") }}`